# Android app freeze if back pressed too soon when starting a new activity

Tags: android

I have an Android app which should download a pdf file and open it when fully downloaded.
I open the pdf file using the startActivityForResult:

```
Intent openPdfintent = new Intent();
openPdfintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
openPdfintent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(openPdfintent, OPEN_PDF_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The problem is that if the back button on the phone is pressed before the pdf file is completely loaded on the screen, onActivityForResult is neved called and the screen is frozen.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

The problem is not when pressing back while downloding the file. It is when opening the file. The download finished ok (I used DownloadManager) and I am trying to open the pdf. I use an implicit intent to open it and while the application selected to open my pdf is actually loading the file (for a short moment of time there appears a white screen), I press back. I can see again my initial activity, but there is no user input and everything is frozen.

Comment: Do you open the PDF on your application (so on a different Activity) or do you just leave the choice to the user to chose another application to do it ?

Comment: The user selects the application to open the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

`Override` your back pressed event to `finish()` the `Activity`.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: I am using an implicit intent to open the pdf file, so I don't have access to the component that actually opens the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
           AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(HourlyEntry.this);

           alertbox.setTitle("PLease wait");
           alertbox.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
                  // finish used for destroyed activity

                   wait();
               }
           });



           alertbox.show();
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }


   public void wait()
   {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    startActivity(i); 
   }
```

Comment: try this... when back is pressed while file downlaoding

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not clear enough. The problem is not when pressing back while downloding the file. It is when opening the file. The download finished ok (I used DownloadManager) and I am trying to open the pdf. I use an implicit intent to open it and while the application selected to open my pdf is actually loading the file (for a short moment of time there appears a white screen), I press back. I can see again my initial activity, but there is no user input and everything is frozen.